# How to join WAV files using PHP?

Tags: php, audio, wav

I need to create a WAV file in PHP that consists of four repetitions of a single WAV (ie. append the uploaded file to itself 3 times). Can anyone suggest a simple way of repeating the data portion of the wav file?

I've tried using [this script](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2006-11/15-joining_wavs_with_php) to join the file to itself four times, but the resulting file always seems to consist of a repetition of only the first 0.2s or so (the exact length seems to vary per file) of the file. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the WAV file format to be able to figure out what's wrong with this script.

The WAV files we're using are always Stereo 16-bit 44.1kHz Windows PCM format, so it occurred to me it might be possible to write a much simpler script that just duplicates (quadruplicates?) the audio portion of the file and modifies only the 'size' portion of the header.

Any suggestions / help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: is invoking ffmpeg an option? I'd rather have an external tool do it for me than try to hack it together in PHP.

Comment: Oh, thanks - I hadn't come across that. I suppose it might be, but it would definitely involve a learning curve and my PHP script seems so *nearly* to work, so I'm very keen to find a PHP-based solution if at all possible.

Comment: Actually, the file *does* subsequently get converted to an mp3 by lame encoder... don't suppose it's possible to manage the concatenation with lame too, to avoid introducing another tool into the mix? (I can't find any way to do so, but thought it might be worth asking just in case...)

Comment: Hey, thanks @UkuLoskit: your comment put me on the right track and made me realise that actually an external tool was the way to go. In the end I went for SoX instead of ffmpeg, but I've now got the script working exactly the way I wanted (and much more robust than trying to chop WAV files around in PHP).

Comment: (If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted).

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: I'm trying to merge a group of files in SoX using the splice option. It works great for 2 files, but I'm stumped at cross-fading a batch of files in one command. Could you post your script -or bits of it- as an answer?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I didn't need to crossfade, so I just used the straightforward repeat command:

`sox source.wav destination.wav repeat 3`

This just adds 3 repetitions to the end of the original file, which is exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather have an external tool do it for me than try to hack it together in PHP.

It turns out that this isn't possible with ffmpeg (I Ggoogled it yesterday and found information about doing it with SoX too), but SoX as you found out for yourself.

Usually it is a lot simpler to delegate the complexity of very specific task to a library or an external tool. This is one of these cases.